# How to query db using C# LINQ to get two related fields on join where one of them distincts the result query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Query returns `f.File` field but need to return related with `f.File` field `c.Name` field also .

How to get `f.File` and `c.Name` related fields as a result of the query where result is distinted by `f.File` field?

```
var query = from f in db.FileCommits
            join c in db.Commits
            on f.CommitID equals c.Id
            where (c.WorkspaceId == workspaceId && f.CommitID <= commitId)
            select new{f, c};
var listOfFiles = query
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.c.Id)
    .Select(f => f.f.File)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: _"distinted by f.File field"_?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I need to get unique records by f.File field and related to each of them c.Name field.

Comment: Don't use joins. use proper relations and navigation properties and let EF load the related entities. Your `FileCommit` class should have a `Commit` property. Your `Commit` property should have a `FileCommits` collection. Loading a single `Commit` instance eg with `db.Commits.Single(c=>c.WorkspaceId == workspaceId )` would provide access to all related `FileCommit` instances

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Except related appears to mean `<` in this case. I don't see EF handling queries where the related entities are further filtered smoothly.

Comment: Which `c.Name` do you want to return when you have multiple choices?

Comment: @NetMage in this case I want the newest one ( that has greater `c.Id` )

Comment: @NetMage the relation is `f.CommitID equals c.Id` so it *should* be a property or collection. `commitId` is a query parameter in `f.CommitID <= commitId`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, but how do you tell EF to filter a relationship to only return certain records (e.g. `Commit.FileCommits` will include all related records, right?).

Comment: @MichałGrudzień I don't see any date or time fields to define "newest"?

Comment: @NetMage The same way you filter any entity. You can write `from f in db.FileCommits where f.CommitID<=commitId && f.Commit.WorkspaceId==wksId` . Or you could use `Collection()` and `Query()` as shown in [Querying related entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#querying-related-entities)

Comment: Except it appears he wants the `Commit` object with the related `FileCommit` objects that meet a certain criteria, so starting with `from c in db.Commits` can you filter `c.FileCommits`?